# Remote Access from Windows to Mac

Tags: macos, mac, windows, remote-control

I am interested in using Xcode, but don't currently own a Mac and my dad owns many, but lives far away. What is the best way of remotely accessing his newest Mac running OSX 10.11 so that I can use it at the same time as him, and without an unreasonable amount of lag?

*I realise that this question has been asked before, but I can't find any answers from the last three or four years, so was interested if anything has changed. The best advice I can find so far seems to be using a program called Real VNC to connect via SSH, is this still true?*

Comment: You say "so that I can use it at the same time as him", well when you remote in while you can control the mouse and keyboard so can he at the same time but only one of you can effectively use the computer at a time not both of you.

Comment: @Qiri When you say "use it at the same time as him" what do you mean? Do you mean both of you using the Mac independently in your own sessions (you using Xcode while your dad is doing something else) or both of you sharing the same session?

Comment: Yeah, I mean both using the computer at the same time to do different things. Neither one would be very intense on the resources, but we would each need a different display and to have independent mouse and keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Any type of VNC would be able to achieve this.

However, a far simpler solution would be to use [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?) which would be much easier to set up & avoid the need to provide a way to punch through the firewall from the outside, as it connects from 'inside' the firewall & is then 'invited in' by the remote party.

TeamViewer is free for non-commercial use.